# Resizing UIPopoverController according to number of ChildViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to create a popover that looks like the below

[image]

Basically, it has three main sections - a header which has some labels in it, a body and a footer which has 2 buttons. The body is made up of a ***variable*** number of `ChildViewControllers`.

**Question**

1) how should I go about doing this? I am thinking in `viewWillAppear` I call a web service which asynchronously returns me the number of ChildViewControllers to create. In the callback method I then create the ChildViewControllers, put them into an array and also add them as ChildViewControllers using `addChildViewController`. Will it be a problem adding ChildViewControllers outside of `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` etc and in the callback method?

2) this view controller is going to appear in a popover. how can I resize the popover in the view controller such that I still get to keep my header and footer (essentially only the centre portion with the varying number of childViewControllers gets adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I implemented this using a `UITableViewController`. The header is a `UIView` implemented as a **table header**. While the two buttons are put into a `UIView` as the **table footer**. ChildViewControllers are put into `UITableViewCell`s. I then disabled scrolling on the `UITableView`.

This method made it very easy to achieve the variable height of the center portion while retaining header and footer.